# Premiere Ignoring DNG file grade

Tags: adobe, premiere, magic-lantern

I have an image sequence of DNG files. I have opened one of these files in Adobe Camera Raw (Photoshop CC) and tweaked it, saving the settings. I've then batch processed all the images in ACR using this setting. I can open any of the images and see the settings are applied.

However when I import the image sequence into Premiere CC, all the settings are ignored and the image is rendered as it was before it was tweaked.

Why is Premiere ignoring the DNG settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is the 'expected behaviour'. Certainly not what I expected.

It seems that ACR doesn't play well with Premiere. So you can't pre-grade your footage before edit. Adobe expect you to use Speedgrade for your grading, despite the fact it isn't a patch on ACR. Your only option appears to be to bring the image sequence into After Effects which allows you to use ACR on import or by *editing original* at any point. Of course you then lose the speedy rendering of Premiere and all the other good stuff.

Comment: That actually kind of makes sense.  The speedy rendering in Premiere is probably in part due to not having to deal with the not so speedy rendering in ACR.  Thanks for sharing what you found.  It matches up with what I thought was likely the case, but I wasn't sure enough to answer.  Guess I should have probably commented, but glad you found it for sure.